# Magento can't reindex product price after installing extension and changing the price at store view level

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, product-prices

Magento can't reindex product price after installing and changing the price at store view level

> https://my.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/store-view-pricing/

```
2018-08-31T06:14:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value) AS `orig_price`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value)) AS `price`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value)) AS `min_price`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value)) AS `max_price`, `tp`.`min_price` AS `tier_price`, `tp`.`min_price` AS `base_tier`, cs.store_id AS `store_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
 CROSS JOIN `core_website` AS `cw`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.group_id = cs.group_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON (tp.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (tp.website_id = cw.website_id) AND (tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 122 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 122 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tad_price` ON tad_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price.attribute_id = 75 AND tad_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tas_price` ON tas_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_price.attribute_id = 75 AND tas_price.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tad_special_price` ON tad_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_price.attribute_id = 76 AND tad_special_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tas_special_price` ON tas_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_price.attribute_id = 76 AND tas_special_price.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='downloadable') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 app\code\local\Innoexts\StorePricing\Model\Mysql4\Downloadable\Indexer\Price.php(125): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 app\code\core\Mage\Downloadable\Model\Resource\Indexer\Price.php(47): Innoexts_StorePricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer\Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 app\code\core\Mage\Index\controllers\Adminhtml\ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: please check system log for errors if any regarding to the indexing.

Comment: Please check the updated question of error I am getting in system log

Comment: Issue related to extension so please contact with your extension support.

Comment: ok thanks and can you suggest any working link of store view pricing